# How does $A^{-1}Ax = b$ turn into $x = A^{-1}b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Background**: Looking at properties and dealing with [Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) in linear algebra, and reading about [Matrix Inverse(s)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html)
>
> **Even More Background:** I'm given a matrix $A$, I found it's inverse i.e.: $A^{-1}$, and now they haven me some $b$ vector and have told me to solve for $x$ since we have $Ax = b$
>
> **Problem**: I don't understand how $A^{-1}Ax = b$ turns into $x = A^{-1}b? $

This may sound like a dumb question but I thought that $A * A^{-1} = I$. I don't understand what they are doing here.

I tried dividing by an $A$

$A^{-1}Ax/A = b/A \implies A^{-1}x = bA^{-1}$ which doesn't work...

I then tried dividing by a $A^{-1}$ which doesn't work either. What am I missing here. I know this is trivial

Comment: It doesn't.  But $Ax=b$ "turns into" $x=A^{-1}b$ (if $A$ is invertible) by multiplying on both sides *on the left* by $A^{-1}$.  Also you shouldn't think of *dividing* by matrices.  Just think of *multiplying* by the inverse of a matrix (on either the left or right of an expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a typo to me.

What is true is that if $A$ is a matrix whose inverse $A^{-1}$ exists, we have

$$\begin{align*}Ax = b &\iff A^{-1} Ax = A^{-1} b \\ 
&\iff Ix = A^{-1}b\\
&\iff x = A^{-1}b\\\end{align*}$$

This is the matrix version of the usual rule with numbers: $ax = b \iff x = b/a$. With matrices, you can only "divide by" matrices that have an inverse.

You are exactly right that $A^{-1}A = I$; this is the fact I used when going from the second equation to the third.

Comment: Can I ask you a dumb question; How did you get rid of your $I$?

Comment: In the step before you get $x = A^{-1}b$ you had an $I$, where did it go?

Comment: That's a fine question. Multiplying an identity matrix $I$ behaves like multiplying the number 1 in arithmetic --- for any matrix/vector $A$ (of appropriate size), you have that $I\times A = A$.  To *see* that this is true, invent a matrix $A$ filled with numbers of your choice and perform the matrix multiplication $I\times A$.

Comment: Oh yea! That Makes complete sense now!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

What they probably meant is that is that if $Ax=b$ and $A$ is invertible then we may multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ on the left to get $A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}b$, or $x=A^{-1}b$.

You have to multiply BOTH sides when you do something.